# "Forcing" Conformance to a Generic Constraint

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have a class, `Target<T>` that cannot be altered, with a generic constraint.  I want to possibly build instances of that class from a generic class that has no constraint.  The following demonstrates the intent of what I want to do, but I realize that this code will not compile and that `typeof(T).IsClass` is a runtime check and the generic constraints are compile-time concerns.

```
public class TargetMaker<T>
{
    public object GetTarget()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsClass)
        {
            return new Target<T>();
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class Target<T> where T : class
{
    public Target() { }
}
```

Can anyone think of a way that I can achieve what I want here in TargetMaker without adding a matching constraint to it, while keeping all of the logic in the TargetMaker class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mind using reflection? If not:

```
if (typeof(T).IsClass)
{
    Type targetType = typeof(Target<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
    return Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);
}
...
```

If performance is a concern, there are probably ways of optimizing it - such as building factory delegates via expression trees, and caching them. That's going to be a lot of hassle if performance *isn't* a problem though :)

Comment: Good idea. `typeof(T).IsClass` is already reflection - is it considerably faster than the new code?

Comment: @Kobi: `typeof(T).IsClass` will be pretty fast though, compared with the `Activator.CreateInstance` call. (At least, that's what I'd expect. If I really cared, I'd test of course :)

Comment: The two lines you added. He already had `typeof(T).IsClass`. Anyway, good answer, let us not dwell on this `:)`. Thanks!